# React component state do not change after setting it on button click

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-hooks, custompaging

I'm Still learning react hooks so bear with me; I'm writing a custom server side pagination component; then for loop through the pages to render them like so :

```
const [activePageNumber, setActivePageNumber] = useState(1);

   for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) {
      if (activePageNumber > 0 && i == activePageNumber)
        rows.push(
          <li
            key={i}
            className="paginate_button page-item active"
            onClick={() => {
              setActivePageNumber(i);
              console.log(activePageNumber);
            }}
          >
            <a className="page-link">{i}</a>
          </li>
        );
      else
        rows.push(
          <li
            key={i}
            className="paginate_button page-item"
            onClick={() => {
              setActivePageNumber(i);
              console.log(activePageNumber);
            }}
          >
            <a className="page-link">{i}</a>
          </li>
        );
    }
```

and the jsx as following :

```
<ul className="pagination">
    {rows}
</ul>
```

the server returning 4 pages and they got rendered properly on the screen; however the problem is whenever I click any page button activePageNumber is always 1 its not changed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are building the entire html outside of `return`, so `i` will always default to last number for every `li` element in the `rows` list when you try to render it inside your `ul`

Instead you should add all this logic inside your `return` statement.

Have a look at [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-dream-tp4x6)

Comment: So its safe to remove the for and replace it with [...Array(12).keys()] instead ?

Comment: it is safe but you need to add this code inside your return statement, not outside. this is the key part, check the sandbox to see how it is called.

Comment: I have no idear what this code is doing! [...Array(pages).keys()]
              .map((a) => a + 1)
              .map((idx) =>

Comment: it creates an array of 0,1,2,3,4... and then it maps it to 1,2,3,4,5 in order to start from 1 not zero. just js fun :)

Comment: it worked thanks; maybe this is another question I'm calling a function on a parent component to re-render a table data activePageNumber become 1 again !

Comment: didnt understand what you said actually. can you add a sandbox? thnx!